# Is it practical to deploy an asterisk server using Docker?

Tags: docker

This is not a question about the production worthiness of either docker or asterisk but whether the containerization makes sense for configuration management and production deployment etc? Specially when adding baremetal is relatively common (about one server a month)?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to elaborate on this question with specifics.  What specifically about Asterisk's configuration management or production deployment details separates it from other software to suggest that it may be impractical?  Are there use cases that you've encountered which might need to be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer right now is 'maybe', but it will get better in the future.

Linux Containers (LXC) are more efficient and lower-latency than VMs. It's no different than running a normal process, but the kernel provides some extra isolation. So LXC has a lot less overhead and less latency than a normal VM.

On the other hand, docker is designed to be non-persistent, so by default, you loose all your data when you stop the server. Your best bet is is to specify `-v` to mount a directory from the host to your docker container. Then just make sure all your settings are stored there.

Comment: but what about mapping a range of UDP ports?  Every example I see describes TCP and is limited to specific port numbers. Asterisk uses large ranges of UDP ports?

Comment: For single ports: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/port_redirection/  Instead of ranges, you should allocate entire IP addresses: http://blog.docker.io/2013/04/unionize-network-superpowers-for-your-docker-containers/

Comment: Your docker container gets its own IP address where it can bind ports as much as it wants. You can then use a firewall rule to forward port ranges to the container.

Comment: You can use --net=host to use the host interface and ports, or you can expose ports ranges in the latest versions of docker